# How to get correct length of a tuple whose constituent elements include list objects?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples

**Question: How can I return the expected length of a tuple when its constituent element is a list object?**

I wrote a very basic unit testing class in Python to begin learning TDD. I want to allow my class to dynamically assign the test case inputs (stored as tuples) depending on how many elements that tuple has. However, when I check the length of a tuple whose only element is a list object the length returned is that of the list object - not the tuple.

Expected functionality:

```
a = (['a', 'b', 'c'])
len(a) # 1 - one element in the tuple
```

Actual functionality:

```
a = (['a', 'b', 'c'])
len(a) # 3 - which appears to be returning len(a[0])
```

Now in the case of a tuple which has **multiple** elements (including list objects) it does return the expected tuple length. So my issue appears to only crop up when the **only element** in the tuple is a list object.

Here is the simple unit tester class I wrote. Right now I am getting around this issue by using an **else clause on line 13**. This doesn't seem like the correct way to handle this.

```
class Unit_Tester:
  def __init__(self, function, tests):
    self.function_to_test = function
    self.test_list = tests

  def unit_test(self, function_to_test, test_input, expected_output):
      try:
          number_of_inputs = len(test_input)
          print(number_of_inputs)
          if number_of_inputs == 1: function_output = function_to_test(test_input)
          elif number_of_inputs == 2: function_output = function_to_test(test_input[0], test_input[1])
          elif number_of_inputs == 3: function_output = function_to_test(test_input[0], test_input[1], test_input[2])
          else: function_output = function_to_test(test_input)
      except Exception as error:
          print("Error occurred with test input: [{0}] value: {1}\nError Message: {2}\nCorrect the error and try again.\n"
          .format(type(test_input), test_input, error))
      else:
        try:
            assert function_output == expected_output
            print(self.unit_test_response(True, test_input, function_output, expected_output))
        except AssertionError:
            print(self.unit_test_response(False, test_input, function_output, expected_output))

  def unit_test_response(self, correct, test_input, function_output, expected_output): 
      score = "Test Passed" if correct else "Test Failed" 
      return "{0}\nInput: {1}\nExpected Output: {2}\nFunction Output: {3}\n".format(score, test_input, expected_output, function_output)

  def run_unit_tests(self, function_to_test, test_list):  
      for test_tuple in test_list:
          test_input, expected_output = test_tuple
          self.unit_test(function_to_test, test_input, expected_output)

  def run(self):
    self.run_unit_tests(self.function_to_test, self.test_list)
```

Comment: `(['a', 'b', 'c'])` isn't a tuple, it's just a list expression with parentheses around it. A one-element tuple needs a comma: `(['a', 'b', 'c'],)`

Comment: ah brilliant thank you. I am new to Python. looking at this problem now that I've stated it I'm wondering if I would be better accepting a list instead. expecting a user (or myself lol) to remember to add that trailing comma seems like an easy oversight

Comment: It's kind of unusual to have a tuple whose length you don't know in advance. A list might be better. You might consider posting over on Code Review SE if you have working code and want to know how to make it better.

Comment: ill do that - thanks. originally i was using a spread operator to distribute the inputs (for a multi-parameter test function) but this obviously failed when encountering a list input (because it spread the list)

Comment: If you do go to Code Review, note that they have [different topicality guidelines](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and rules than Stack Overflow, and the [How to Ask](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page is also different.